# Javascript cookies creation

Tags: javascript, cookies

When creating a cookie using javascript using document.cookie

> document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; " + expires + ";path=/";

will the domain be populated or do I need to specify it?

Comment: I can't set the domain locally and I don't have anywhere to deploy it yet.

Comment: OK, but you could try on any other website using the Developer Console.

Comment: haven't thought of that, thanks! I am new to web development:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create cookies for the domain that your script is running under. So yes, the browser will set the cookie for the proper domain.

[image]

Comment: Like "what does it do" or "why did I specify it in my example"?

Comment: I am curious, what does it do? The RFC 6265 doesn't mention anything regarding a `Session` attribute oO: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265

Answer (score 1):

It will be populated.

You can run this in the console and then look at the cookies and Domain will be populated.

```
document.cookie = "val=val;Session;path=/";
```